# What does Bhagvata Purana tell about Arjun-Subhadra love affair ? Was it one-sided only from Subhadra side?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, arjuna, subhadra

What does Bhagvata Purana tells about love story between Arjun and Subhadra ? Was it one sided only from Subhadra side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Both wanted each other as per the Bhāgavatam.

Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) » Canto 10: The Summum Bonum

##### [Chapter Eighty-Six](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/86/?query=subhadra#bb74648): Summary

> When King Parīkṣit desired to learn about the marriage of his
> grandmother, Subhadrā-devī, Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said, “While touring
> on pilgrimage, Arjuna heard that Lord Baladeva intended to give the
> hand of His sister Subhadrā to Duryodhana in marriage. Wanting to
> kidnap Subhadrā and marry her himself, Arjuna disguised himself as a
> renunciant and went to Dvārakā. So effective was the disguise that
> neither Balarāma nor any other resident of Dvārakā recognized him;
> rather, they all showed him the respect due a Vaiṣṇava mendicant. In
> this way the four months of the rainy season passed. One day Arjuna
> received an invitation to dine at Lord Balarāma’s home. There he
> caught sight of Subhadrā and was immediately overwhelmed with desire
> for her. Subhadrā also desired to have Arjuna as her husband, and thus
> she glanced back at him shyly.

##### Relevant Verses

> [ŚB 10.86.6](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/86/6/)
>
> सोऽपश्यत्तत्र महतीं कन्यां वीरमनोहराम् । प्रीत्युत्फुल्ल‍ेक्षणस्तस्यां
> भावक्षुब्धं मनो दधे ॥ ६ ॥
>
> > 6. **There he saw the wonderful maiden Subhadrā, who was enchanting to heroes. His eyes opened wide with delight, and his mind became
> >    agitated and absorbed in thoughts of her.**
>
> [ŚB 10.86.7](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/86/7/)
>
> सापि तं चकमे वीक्ष्य नारीणां हृदयंगमम् । हसन्ती व्रीडितापाङ्गी
> तन्न्यस्तहृदयेक्षणा ॥ ७ ॥
>
> > 7. **Arjuna was very attractive to women, and as soon as Subhadrā saw him, she wanted to have him as her husband. Smiling bashfully with
> >    sidelong glances, she fixed her heart and eyes upon him.**